# Android: Best way to link two View Models

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

TLDR: Basically I two viewmodels one is responsible for data from the database, the other is responsible for keeping up with a range of dates the user is currently viewing. I want to take the date range from viewmodel(b) and use it to update viewmodel(a). My current thinking is to pass viewmodel(b) as a parameter into a constructor method of viewmodel(a) and have live data notify it whenever the paramaters change.

So I have a DBViewModel that essentially pulls events from a database. These events are simply am object the user can enter their own parameters that contain a timestamp.

I than have implemented my own version of a calendar(I don't much care for the provided android calendar). This uses a CalendarViewModel to keep up with the date range that the user is currently viewing. They can scroll into the past and future.

I have got this working by putting the date info inside the DBViewModel class previously and had it keep up with everything. However, it wasn't maintainable and contained over 800 lines of code.

I made the decision to separate the logic into two classes and now am finding it hard to find any documentation on passing in arguments into a viewmodel so that I can have the data from the CalendarViewModel as a parameter inside DBViewModel and use it to update the timestamps to query the database. The reason for wanting to decouple the viewmodels is simply to follow best practice, and I have other fragments that simply will just use DBViewModel and don't neccesarily need the CalendarViewModel logic and variables. It basically just helps with efficency.

[image: Class Hierachy of code structure]

Comment: Why you have 2 `ViewModel` in first place . A single `ViewModel` will work . Apart from that passing VM into another VM is not a good idea IMO .

Comment: I have two viewmodels because the DBViewModel is used in other parts of the application and don't neccesarily need all the variables, logic, and generating of variables from the CalendarViewModel. The CalendarViewModel sole responsibility is to keep up with the dates the user is currently viewing or has scrolled to, and I want to use that date range as a sort of auto-query to pull the events from the DBViewModel.

I also decided to separate them to follow androids recommendation of a single class per responsibility principle.

Comment: ^ I guess a better way to say that is that I want the CalendarViewModel to change the dates the DBViewModel queries from the repo automatically.

Comment: Thats what i meant if you wanna keep up with it . You can ovserve on a VM and Change the corresponding value or call methods in second ViewModel .

Comment: Pffffft that sounds so obvious now. Thanks man/woman, tunnel vision is real.